# Random error in Android Studio 'R'

Tags: android

I opened the project now, that I 've been working on for past few weeks. And all of a sudden `R` seems as an error, and is underlined with red. R as in:

```
 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_quotes2);`
```

What is the best possible fix and what is causing this?

Comment: Try to rebuild the project. Build->Rebuild. Does it compile? Can you run it?

Comment: Yes , it fixed the issue. But, why a sudden error. Is that a problem with Android studio? Or anything wrong from my side :(  ?

Comment: Android studio probably hadn't synced the gradle files, happends.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R cannot be resolved - Android error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/r-cannot-be-resolved-android-error)

Comment: I've posted the answer from the comment below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to rebuild the project. Build->Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Re-build the project.

This happens quite commonly in Android Studio. I'm not sure when the bug will be fixed because it's been this way for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

You need check all layouts in your project. In some place you has and error or You can check the SDK installed in your computer. Try update.